# Angular: passing all directive from parent component to child transparently

Tags: html, angular, directive

Let's have a component named `parent` which uses another one named `child`.

I'd want that, when in the client, a directive is passed to `parent`, e.g:

```
<parent dir1='dirval1'></parent>
```

the parent acts as a thin wrapper and forward this directive to `child`, ultimately calling child like this:

```
<child dir1='dirval1'></parent>
```

Is that possible in angular, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not impossible. If you want to customize a "child" component with directive outside of the "parent" component, you can use ng-content like this:

"main" component template:

```
<parent>
  <child dir1="dirval1"></child>
</parent>
```

and in "parent" component template we simply change to:

```
//...some other template logic/layout
// and here where previously was child component we write instead:
<ng-content></ng-content>
```